# How to disable Macbook Pro from switching to a high performance graphics card in Cocoa?

Tags: macos, cocoa, graphics, gpu

All 2010 Macbook Pros come with two graphics cards — a low-performance built-in Intel HD one and a high-performance discrete NVIDIA one — and it switches between them on the fly depending on the needs of the running applications.

I have a simple Cocoa application that consists of just a menu bar item with a `NSTextField` in it. All I do is update the text field with an `NSAttributedString` from time to time. The trouble is that my application switches my Macbook Pro to use the high-performance NVIDIA card (I used the [gfxCardStatus](http://codykrieger.com/gfxCardStatus/) tool to confirm this).

What could possibly need the high-performance card? Is there a known list of reasons for the applications to require high-performance graphics card? Is there a way to force the computer to use the discrete graphics card?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is a good article about GPU switching in the newer MacBook Pros at [Ars Technica](http://arstechnica.com/apple/news/2010/04/inside-apples-automatic-gpu-switching.ars).
I noticed that OS X switches to the dedicated GPU if you

- Start an application that links against OpenGL
- Connect a second display

The code of gfxCardStatus is open source. And it seems that the relevant part is located in switcher.m. You can take a closer look [here](https://github.com/codykrieger/gfxCardStatus/blob/b6d491236cc4efcb78bf1bb2a6d57e6faa959a53/switcher.m).

Comment: Thanks for the plug. :) It is indeed open source, and I encourage you to look at it should you desire - however, I would not recommend adding the switching code into other applications. One application trying to control which GPU is active is enough. I managed to corrupt one of my kernel extensions by running 3 copies of it simultaneously and trying to switch with each of them right after the other, just for testing purposes - bad idea.

Comment: Additionally, anything that uses CALayers will trigger a switch to the discrete GPU.

Comment: That was it Cody! As soon as I set wantsLayer on one of the controls to NO it stopped switching to discrete GPU. You should put it down as an answer.

Answer (score 8):

In MacOS 10.7 you can specify a setting in the PList to stop going to discrete graphics:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1734/_index.html

Needs to be a 2011+ MacBook Pro.

Comment: Also needs to be 15" or 17" (not 13")